# How to use Jena ARQ in Maven?

Tags: maven, jena, arq

We are trying to develop an extension for Jena ARQ by adding a new operator. We are wondering how to use jena and/or arq in maven to fulfill this task. We see a number of maven artifacts out there. Can somebody give us a hint or an example which artifact(s) we should use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Documented at http://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the jena artifact for our extension. However, while I was trying to built the project, I got several errors. Most of them were caused by "The import org.apache.jena.ext cannot be resolved". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I kinda solved the problem by using an older version of jena (2.13.0).

Comment: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/migrate_jena2_jena3.html